# To find the frequency of a number in an array using recursion

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

My code blocks is giving an error.But i'm not able to find it anywhere in the

program.  it's saying

> in Line 3 :expected ';',',' or ')' before '=' token

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int count_key1(int a[],int size,int key,int flag=0)
 {

     if(size!=0)
         {
             if(a[size-1]==key)
                 count_key1(a,size--,key,flag++);
         }
     else
        return flag;
 }
 int main()
 {
     int b[30]={1,4,2,3,2,6,6,9},key1=9,result;
     result=count_key1(b,8,key1,0);
     printf("%d is %d times present",key1,result);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You realize that this could as well have been written as `int count=0; for(i=0; i<size; i++) { if (b[i] == key) { count++; } }` which is vast improvement from the extremely inefficient, unreadable recursion.

Comment: this is not permitted in c language `int flag=0`

Comment: You should write int main (void). Also you should write the prototype for your function.

Comment: How does the question related to its title?

Comment: you cannot give your args a default value in c.. also, i don't know that its necessary but it will help everyone (especial you)  if you explicitly return after returning from the recursion.

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. It will not generate that message.

Answer (score 9):

In C, you cannot assign a *default value* in function parameter.

Remove `=0` in

```
  int count_key1(int a[],int size,int key,int flag=0)
```

IIRC, you got confused with `C++` function overloading, where, we can have some default value to a parameter, if the argument is not passed while calling the function.

However, in C, a function call has to *match exactly* the signature present in the definition. So, basically, there is no need for a *default value* to be present at function definition, as such.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, your code is really appreciable, but try using the following simpler code which gives the same output and is easy to understand

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int count_key1(int* a,int size,int key,int flag)
{
        int count=0,i;
        for(i=0; i<size; i++) { if (a[i] == key)  count++; }
        return count;
}
int main()
{
        int b[30]={1,4,2,3,2,6,6,9},key1=9,result;
        result=count_key1(b,8,key1,0);
        printf("%d is %d times present",key1,result);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i been given a condition that i should use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count(int num, int* arr, int length) {
    if (!length)
        return 0;
    int c = count(num, arr+1, length-1);
    return arr[0] == num? c + 1: c;
}

int main(void) {
int arr[10] = {3,4,1,2,4,5,6,5,4,5};

std::cout << count(2, arr, 10);

return 0;
}
```